# Uploaded file appended to Form Data shows as empty?

Tags: forms, vue.js, axios, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to upload an image file, using vue.js to process it client-side, axios to post to the server, and Laravel as the php server.

On the client side I have:

```html
<script setup>
/*...*/
const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
    uploadedFile = event.target.files[0];
    uploadedFileUrl.value = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};

const saveItem = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', uploadedFile);
    formData.set('name', inputName.value);
    formData.set('type', inputType.value);
    formData.set('price', inputPrice.value);
    formData.set('description', inputDescription.value);
    console.log(formData);

    axios.post('/products', formData)
        .then(function(){
            console.log('SUCCESS!!');
    })
    .catch(function(){
        console.log('FAILURE!!');
    });
};
</script>

<template>
    <form class="row g-3 needs-validation" novalidate @submit.prevent="save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="inputImg" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" @change="handleFileUpload($event)" />
    </form>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="saveItem">Save</button>
</template>
```

When the post request is sent the formData shows correctly, except the file which shows as empty in the request. The console log of formData shows:

```bash
FormData(5) { file → {}, name → "testItem", type → "hot dish", price → "1", description → "desc" }
```

But under  it has the File object itself, as can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJbiz.jpg

I've googled around and most tutorials and showcases say that simply appending the file is enough to send it to the server. Adding

```js
headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
```

to axios does not help, as the file always shows as empty.